Dynamically loading content into div on scroll in jQuery
I have a table inside a div with overflow. I want to dynamically load content when scrolling. There are 100 elements in the table. I want to load new content when element number 90 is at the top of the parent div. How to determine that the element with Heading number 90 is at the top of the div with overflow?
I mean I solved this problem with code:
function isVisible(el, table) {
        let docViewTop = table[0].getBoundingClientRect();  
         let el_rect = el[0].getBoundingClientRect();
        return (docViewTop.top <= el_rect.top) && (docViewTop.bottom >= el_rect.bottom);
}


Pls provide your code attempt and what you have tried for a better help. Pls note that you Can certainly achieve what you want using intersectionObserver API. There are great tutorials on the web
